# Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 price is hacking

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. Some Hackers are hacking the website. They are decreasing the price 96% at evening and users are purchasing the item at cheaper price. I am not able to figure out magento 1.7.0.2 security threads. Please suggestion me how can stop this hack.

Is there SQL Injection?
Any Script?
Bot attack?

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Update your shop to 1.9

Comment: Could you suggest other solution. We can't update it 1.9 as of now. I appreciate your response.

Comment: You'd better have a go at [Magento problem report system](https://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking) to search if it is a known problem and create a new problem ticket (if they still support your version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has Promotion Rules. I have created the Promotional rule for shopping cart and then i directly deleted it before disabled. So when user register with store. He is getting discount.